# Add/edit a dns record in windows machine

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns

I want to do something I thought was simple, 
I want in my machine, to edit the dns record for domain.com to one ip I want.

The reason to do this is I am trying to move some websites to another server and I want to test that everything is working ok on the new server before I change the dns entries of the domain.

I tried searching and I couldn't find anything useful, or easy, I tried added the entry to the windows hosts file, and flushed the dns settings, but still no luck. I keep getting the old ip.

What is the way to do this ?

Comment: Hosts should work. Can you take a screenshot of your host entry? Can you also tell us the domain you are wanting to redirect? Make sure you include the main domain and the sub domain in hosts if you intend to use both (such as www.google.com and google.com)

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the "hosts" file, and possibly restart your browser. Have a look at this [link.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) to find the specific location and format of it.